# moving docker-compose images between hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

based on [Moving docker-compose containersets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024216/moving-docker-compose-containersets-around-between-hosts)

I have loaded the images :

```
$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
br/irc              latest              3203cf074c6b        23 hours ago        377MB
openjdk             8u131-jdk-alpine    a2a00e606b82        5 days ago          101MB
nginx               1.13.3-alpine       ba60b24dbad5        4 months ago        15.5MB
```

but now i want to run them, as they would run with docker-compose, but i cannot find any example.

here is the  docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  irc:
    build: irc
    hostname: irc
    image: br/irc:latest
    command: |
      -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
      -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses
      run-app
    volumes:
      - ./br/assets/br.properties:/opt/br/src/java/br.properties
  nginx:
    hostname: nginx
    image: nginx:1.13.3-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - irc:irc
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/assets/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

so how can i run the container, and attach to it, to see if its running, and in what order do i run these three images. Just started with docker, so not sure of the typical workflow ( build, run, attach etc )

so even though i do have docker-compose yml file, but since i have the build images from another host, can i possibly run docker commands to run and execute the images ? making sure that the local images are being referenced, and not the ones from docker registry.

Thanks @tgogos, this does give me a general overview, but specifically i was looking for:

```
$ docker run -dit openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine
then:
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
cc6ceb8a82f8        openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine   "/bin/sh"                52 seconds ago      Up 51 seconds                                   vibrant_hodgkin

shows its running

2nd:

$ docker run -dit nginx:1.13.3-alpine
3437cf295f1c7f1c27bc27e46fd46f5649eda460fc839d2d6a2a1367f190cedc


$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
3437cf295f1c        nginx:1.13.3-alpine        "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   20 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds               80/tcp              vigilant_kare
cc6ceb8a82f8        openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine   "/bin/sh"                2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                    vibrant_hodgkin


then: finally:

[ec2-user@ip-10-193-206-13 DOCKERLOCAL]$ docker run -dit br/irc
9f72d331beb8dc8ccccee3ff56156202eb548d0fb70c5b5b28629ccee6332bb0

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
9f72d331beb8        br/irc              "/opt/irc/grailsw"       8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds                8080/tcp            cocky_fermi
3437cf295f1c        nginx:1.13.3-alpine        "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   56 seconds ago      Up 55 seconds               80/tcp              vigilant_kare
cc6ceb8a82f8        openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine   "/bin/sh"                2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                    vibrant_hodgkin

All three UP !!!!
```

Comment: I added some extra info to my answer about `docker-compose`. To say the truth, I am not quite sure what your question is, but I am here to help if you want. Actually, you ask about `docker-compose` which is a tool that does many things in the background (e.g. `docker-compose up`  builds `images`, (re)creates / starts / attaches to `containers` and then you update your question saying that you were looking for simple docker commands like `docker run` and `docker ps`.

Comment: @tgogos I truly appreciate your explanations, and they help. I am only reverting to docker commands, as I could not find equivalent in docker-compose. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about `docker-compose` but you also ask things about `run`, `build`, `attach` which makes me think I should try to help you with some basic information (which wasn't so easy for me to cope with a couple of months ago :-)

## `images`

Images are somehow the base from which `containers` are created. Docker pulls images from http://hub.docker.com and stores them in your host to be used every time you create a new container. Changes in the container do not affect the base image.

To pull images from docker hub, use `docker pull ...`. To build your own images start reading about `Dockerfiles`. A simple Dockerfile (in an abstract way) would look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu                  # base image
ADD my_super_web_app_files   # adds files for your app
CMD run_my_app.sh            # starts serving requests
```

To create the above image to your host, you use `docker build ...` and this is a very good way to build your images, because you know the steps taken to be created.

If this procedure takes long, you might consider later to store the image in a `docker registry` like http://hub.docker.com, so that you can `pull` it from any other machine easily. I had to do this, when dealing with [`ffmpeg`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tgogos/ffmpeg/) on a Raspberry Pi (the compilation took hours, I needed to `pull` the already created image, not `build` it from scratch again in every Raspberry).

## `containers`

Containers are based on images, you can have many different containers from the same image on the same host. `docker run [image]` creates a new container based on that image and starts it. Many people here start thinking containers are like mini-VMs. They are not!

Consider a container as a **process**. Every container has a `CMD` and when started, executes it. If this command finishes, or fails, the container stops, exits. A good example for this is `nginx`: go check the official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/dockerfile/nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile), the command is:

```
CMD ["nginx"]
```

If you want to see the logs from the `CMD`, you can `docker attach ...` to your container. You can also `docker stop ...` a running container or `docker start ...` an already stopped one. You can "get inside" to type commands by:

```
docker exec -it [container_name] /bin/bash
```

This opens a new tty for you to type commands, while the `CMD` continues to run.

---

To read more about the above topics (I've only scratched the surface) I suggest you also read:

- [Is it possible to start a shell session in a running container (without ssh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903705/is-it-possible-to-start-a-shell-session-in-a-running-container-without-ssh)
- [Docker - Enter Running Container with new TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932357/docker-enter-running-container-with-new-tty/20932974)
- [How do you attach and detach from Docker's process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688314/how-do-you-attach-and-detach-from-dockers-process)
- [Why docker container exits immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately)
- [~jpetazzo: If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)

---

## `docker-compose`

After you feel comfortable with these, `docker-compose` will be your handy tool which will help you manipulate many containers with single line commands. For example:

```
docker compose up
```

> **Builds**, **(re)creates**, **starts**, and **attaches** to containers for a service.
>
> Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.
>
> The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container (essentially running `docker-compose logs -f`). When the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d` starts the containers in the background and leaves them running

Comment: @togogos now that i have all three container UP, how can i make sure the grails web application is running and on which port ?

Comment: `docker container ls -a` lists all the containers (even the stopped ones). You can check for container details with `docker inspect ...`

Answer (score 0):

To run your docker-compose file you would have to execute:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Then to see if your containers are running you would have to run:

```
docker ps
```

This command will display all the running containers

Then you could run the *exec* command which will allow you to enter inside a running container:

```
docker-compose exec irc
```

More about docker-compose up here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: How can i make sure that the local images are being used ? since docker-compose up does run, but on THIS host, it gives me compile issues, hence i build the docker images on another host, and copied them to this one.