# How to restart an Azure Function inside a Linux container?

Tags: .net, azure, docker, azure-functions, containers

I run an azure funciton locally inside a docker container using this base image:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0
```

When having a look at the docker files (here for example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/dev/host/2.0/stretch/amd64/dotnet/dotnet.Dockerfile), I see the */azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost* library invoked at startup. However, I couldn't find any option to stop the running azure function and re-start it without restarting the whole container, so my question is:

How can I restart an azure function inside a linux container without restarting the whole container?

Comment: There does seem to be a route available to restart the host.  See here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/38447cd390b7b66900685c4a15a1ad548a6d6f53/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Controllers/HostController.cs#L236).  You would have to figure out how to authenticate to it and invoke it.  Out of curiousity, why not just restart the container?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I could invoke this route and restart the service, I wasn't aware that these files were on github. Authentication I could do by following these methods https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4147

I am working on some testing framework for azure functions in docker where I like to test different behaviors of our functions and don't want to restart the whole container all the time

Answer (score 0):

By Using `Docker` you ***cannot restart*** the specific **services**. It can restart the container.

```
docker restart [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
```

Instead of `Docker` you need to use `Docker-Compose`. It will give the option for ***restart the specific service***.

```
 restart [options] [SERVICE...]
```

Options:

```
-t, --timeout TIMEOUT  Specify a shutdown timeout in seconds. (default: 10)
```

[Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/restart/) Vs [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/)

To use the Docker Compose [check here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/)

Refer  [moving-docker-compose-containersets-around-between-hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024216/moving-docker-compose-containersets-around-between-hosts) & [azure-functions-express-running-azure-functions-locally-using-docker-compose](https://gopensource.com/azure-functions-express-running-azure-functions-locally-using-docker-compose-bf6be03250fc)